# [Android Studio 3.1 ]Program type already present: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException Message

Tags: android

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    multiDexEnabled true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    resConfigs "en", "es"
}
```

I am getting below exception while running the application, sync is success but getting below exception.

Program type already present: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: Hi, Did you got the solution for this?

Comment: I updated Studio and build tools and worked.

Comment: Yes Karthik, worked for me with latest 3.4 update.